# How to generate predictions based on the distribution of the data using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

My dataframe currently looks like this (lets call this df_1).

```
date   var1 
1-1-01 0.1   
2-1-01 0.02 
3-1-01 3.00   
4-1-01 4.5   
5-1-01 0.9   
6-1-01 0.22
```

The `var_1`  is normally distributed. (see photo below)
[image]

I have another data frame that simply consists of dates with no value of var1 (lets call this df_2):

```
date   var1 
1-2-01    
2-2-01 
3-2-01 
4-2-01 
5-2-01 
6-2-01
```

I simply want predictions based on random draw from the normal distribution of var1 in df_1. How can I do  this in python?

PS: Do not worry about the kurtosis (height) of the distribution at 0. I know it is the highest. Think of it like the mean of the distribution (as well as the median and mode) is 0. I want to make sure that this fact is taken into account when making predictions.

Comment: If you have a significant amount of data, you can do time-series prediction.

Comment: @Patel Thankyou for your input. I am fully aware that I can use time-series prediction too. I am doing this to have a baseline accuracy score for my model. I will build on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit a normal distribution to `var_1`, and then draw samples from it,

```py
import scipy
import numpy as np

# fit to var_1
mu, std = scipy.stats.norm.fit(df['var_1'])

# generate data for var_2
var_2 = np.random.normal(mu, std, size=len(df['var_1']))
```

But please note what you're asking ignores the dates, which means you're ignoring any time series structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @stevemo. I just wanted to ask you if the code snippet that you wrote will have the same characteristics of the distribution of  ```var_1``` . What do I mean by that? We know that the kurtosis value of a normal distribution is 3. Lets say that the value of kurtosis of var_1's distribution is 2.90. Will your code make sure that this characteristic is taken into account?

Comment: You asked to fit a normal distribution, which is completely characterized by its second order statistics, i.e. mean and variance.  So no, if you want to enforce empirical estimates of higher moments, you'll need to pick a different distribution.

Comment: I get it now. The solution you gave makes sense. I used your code but just wanted to confirm if the final values of var2 will have the same range as the initial distribution or that of the standard normal distribution, i.e., -3 to 3